# TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, mongodb, discord, discord.py, pymongo

I am trying to create  a discord bot with python as language and mongodb as database.
I am creating this command to update the troops amount but when I run this command it shows **TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable**. I think there is a problem with the function in the $set line but once it works fine but now it shows error. I don't know how to fix it?. If someone knows how to fix this problem please rectify this code and help me.

**This is the error message**

```
Ignoring exception in command train:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\code\kingdom fight\main.py", line 261, in training
    't1': res['tier1'], 't2': res['tier2'], 't3': res['tier3'], 'potions': res['training_train_pot']}})
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable
C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\events.py:80: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Command.__call__' was never awaited
  self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

**The error is in this line**

```
 await update_data(filtr, {'$set': {
                't1': res['tier1'], 't2': res['tier2'], 't3': res['tier3'], 'potions': res['training_train_pot']}})
```

```py
@bot.command(name="train")  # Training the soldiers
# tier -  troop tier to train, Amount - No. of troops to train
async def training(ctx: commands.Context, tier: int = None, amount: int = None):
    '' Used to train troops `?train <tier> <troops_amount>` Eg: ||?train 3 100||''
    if(tier == None or amount == None):
        await ctx.send("Give the argument correctly like `?train <tier> <troops_amount>`")
    elif(user_info.find_one({'id': ctx.author.id})):
        if user_info.find_one({'id': ctx.author.id}) == None:
            await ctx.send('Please start using `?start`!')
        get_data = user_info.find_one({'id': ctx.author.id})
        update_data = user_info.find_one_and_update
        filtr = {'id': ctx.author.id}
        # print(get_data)
        res = train(amount, get_data['potions'], tier,
                    get_data['t1'], get_data['t2'], get_data['t3'])
        if(res == "Not enough training potions"):
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}You dont have enough potions')
        elif(res == "No such tier troops exist"):
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}No such tier exists. Tiers available are 1-3')
        else:
            await update_data(filtr, {'$set': {
                't1': res['tier1'], 't2': res['tier2'], 't3': res['tier3'], 'potions': res['training_train_pot']}})
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}You have successfully trained {amount} tier {tier} troops")
    elif(user_info.find_one({'id': ctx.author.id}) == None):
        await ctx.reply('Please start using `?start` command')
    else:
        await ctx.send("Give the argument correctly like `?train <tier> <troops_amount>`")
```

This is the `train` function

```py
p_t1 = 1
p_t2 = 8
p_t3 = 20  # training potions of t1,t2,t3
train_pot = 0
def train(troop_count, train_pot, tier, t1, t2, t3):
    if(tier == 1):
        if(troop_count*p_t1 > train_pot):  # checks whether we have enough training costs for training t1
            result = "Not enough training potions"
            return result
        else:
            train_pot = train_pot-troop_count*p_t1  # if yes train the tier 1 troops
            t1 += troop_count
            result = {
                'training_train_pot': train_pot,
                'tier1': t1,
                'tier2': t2,
                'tier3': t3
            }
            return result
    elif(tier == 2):
        if(troop_count*p_t2 > train_pot):  # checks whether we have enough training costs for training t2
            result = "Not enough training potions"
            return result
        else:  # if yes train the tier 2 troops
            train_pot = train_pot-troop_count*p_t2
            t2 += troop_count
            result = {
                'training_train_pot': train_pot,
                'tier1': t1,
                'tier2': t2,
                'tier3': t3
            }
            return result
    elif(tier == 3):  # checks whether we have enough training costs for training t3
        if(troop_count*p_t3 > train_pot):
            result = "Not enough training potions"
            return result
        else:  # if yes train the tier 3 troops
            train_pot = train_pot-troop_count*p_t3
            t3 += troop_count
            result = {
                'training_train_pot': train_pot,
                'tier1': t1,
                'tier2': t2,
                'tier3': t3
            }
            return result
    else:
        # if we gave invalid tier print no such tier exist
        result = "No such tier troops exist"
        return result
```

Comment: Which line exactly is it complaining about? Post the complete error message with trace back.

Comment: its hard to see without the stacktrace, but this error usually happens when you use [] after await, you should use `(await some_func())['some_key']` instead of `await some_func()['some_key']`

Comment: I edited the message and pasted the traceback error line with my code. Can you help how to fix it?

Comment: What is `train`…? It appears to return a coroutine, so `res` is a coroutine…

Comment: @deceze  i updated the train function also. Can you check it and help me how to prevent returning a couroutine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing the function outside the command. Try running the command without function. Like do all the stuffs that was done inside the function, in inside the command.

Comment: May you please rephrase your answer or provide an example? I think I have a similar issue, but don't seem to understand how to implement your suggestion here.